# Is there a way to output the name of elements and attributes from an XML doc?

Tags: xml, xslt

What I am trying to do is use XSL to output all unique element and attribute names.  Not their values, but their names.

So given an XML of:

```
<item id="12">
  <price>12.00</price>
  <author>Name</author>
  <desc>Description</desc>
</item>
```

I want to show that there are elements of item,price,author,desc.  In addition to that I want to know there is an attribute of 'id'.

Any ideas on how to do this?  Or articles I can read about it?  Is it even possible?

Thanks,
Levi

Comment: btw, your xml sample isn't well-formed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used them a lot myself, but these functions should get you there: [XPath functions on nodes](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp#node). More specifically, look at `name()` and `local-name()`. Since they work on nodes, there should be no problem using them on elements as well as attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="names" match="//* | //@*" use="name()"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="(//* | //@*)[count(key('names', name())) = 1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" /><br />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: More like `<xsl:for-each select="(//* | //@*)[count(. | key('names', name())[1]) = 1]">`, or am I misunderstanding the "unique" requirement?

Comment: I don't think so; I used name() when building 'names' key, so it probably wont match with .